# Is there official session scheduler interface in flink to allow user to customize the session management？

Tags: apache-flink

For flink session cluster, user can start multiple sessions and submit mulitple jobs in each session.
Does flink support session scheduler interface to allow user to customize the scheduler?

Comment: Not sure what this means. Is this a question about Flink YARN sessions, or something else? What sort of scheduling customization do you have in mind?

Comment: Hi David, 

great thanks for your response.